# Vaadin Flow TextField Browser AutoFill

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

According to this old thread:

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18510843/textfield-browser-autofill

It's possible to tell the browser to auto fill a form. I am able to get the browser to populate values by setting the "name" and "autocomplete" attributes, however the browser does not seem to remember new values entered into the Vaadin form. There are appear to be some restrictions on when Chrome/Firefox will do this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) but some of those restrictions are not easily implemented in Vaadin.

Does anyone have an example of auto fill working both directions (browser filling in values and also remembering new values)?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the [LoginForm](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/java-examples), it does what you want.

**Edited :**
Or to control it with vaadin you could try it with this [autosuggest add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/autosuggest/overview) and update the list of suggestions with the new values.

Comment: That only populates the field with values that the browser knows about, using the html "autocomplete" attribute. As far as I can tell it does not trigger the browser to remember new values.